# Android(Java) Producer/Consumer with Timer

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

I am testing a simple producer/ consumer example in android this is what i'm doing.

I have two EditText boxes, one being a producer and the other a consumer. The app also has a single button once this button is pressed two timers start and the producer produces while the consumer consumes. Here is my code:

```
   submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Timer producerTimer = new Timer();
  producerTimer .schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
    producer();
  }
  },100, 300);

  Timer consumerTimer = new Timer();
  consumerTimer .schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
    consumer();
  }
  },100, 300);
}
});

}
```

Now for the other methods:

```
public void producer(){
    this.runOnUiThread(producer_Tick);
}

public void consumer(){
    this.runOnUiThread(consumer_Tick2);
}

private Runnable producer_Tick = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        put(i++);

    }
};

private Runnable consumer_Tick= new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        int result = get();
        consumerBox.append(Integer.toString(result) + "\n");

    }
};
```

Here are my Synchronized methods:

```
public synchronized void put(int val){
    if (!empty){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {Log.d(TAG,"Error Putting");}
    }

    producerBox.append(Integer.toString(val) + "\n");
    empty = false;
    buffer=val;
    notify();
}

public synchronized int get(){
    if (empty){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {Log.d(TAG,"Error getting");}
    }

    empty = true;
    notify();
    return buffer;

}
```

This program runs to random points all the time. Sometimes for a couple of minuites it runs fine where consumer reads from producer etc.. However, everytime, at some point, the program will just freeze at producer and consumer at a certain value (random each time). Does anyone see a problem with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [blocking queue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to communicate between producer-consumer threads in more efficient and easy to understand way.

Comment: thanks for that, you're right that sounds like something i need. however, i'm really not sure how to incorporate that into my code, would you know how i could do something like that?

Comment: @Mark if you take a look at the java docs. you'll have to create and share one single `queue` between producer and consumer timers. in `producer()` do `queue.put` and in `consumer()` do `queue.take`. invoke `runOnUIThread` only when you're updating UI elements

Answer (score 0):

you should use notifyAll(). notify does not gaurantee which thread is notified. Also check hat empty is actually synchronized (i.e. is owned by the status class where get and put reside.).